# obiee12c dashboard prompts running before analysis filters

Tags: oracle, obiee

I have an analysis that uses a filter in order to limit the results.
I put this analysis into a Dashboard together with a Dashboard prompt.
The Dashboard prompt consists of various columns and all of them are of type "Choice list" and all have the option "Limit values by" = "All prompts".
However, this is not working as I expected. I thought that the values appearing in he Choice list should be limited by the filters applied in the analysis but it seems that the dashboard prompt first shows all the possible values before having applied the analysis filter.
Is this correct?
If this is the way it works, the problem I am facing is that some of the values appearing in the Choice list of the prompt columns will result in NO DATA in the analysis.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I thought that the values appearing in he Choice list should be limited by the filters applied in the analysis"

Exactly the other way around. Prompts send their selected values to the filter that's in the analysis and hence cut off the data stream.

It is normal that a prompt retrieves selection values for which *a certain point of view* retrieves no data. Other way round would make no sense. Imagine you sell 5 products and one didn't sell at all in August. Do you want to remove August from your month prompt?

The interdependence of prompts that you mention is for example - limit regions to only regions of a selected country. Limit customers to only customers of a selected business unit etc.

What you write and expect is that the prompt should go over the effective data (facts) and only retrieve values for which data (facts) exists. As said above that's not the most logical thing to do in an analytical environment since one change of point of view can mean that data "exists" or "doesn't exist" - then you change the point of view and the situation changes. And you want that. You don't want to hardcode points of view which over time or when somebody else looks at the data (personalized data security) they will get different results.

Don't hardcode too much. Don't restrict the system artificially.

Update: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cjSD.jpg
Here's a screenshot of where you can restrict the prompt

Comment: Thanks Chris! But imagine that from the 5 products I sell, I have a filter in my analysis to only take into consideration those sold on the first half of the year. When I run this analysis in the dashboard, I want the prompt for the month showing only January to June, cause if the user have the possibility of picking August, this will give NO DATA and it is confusing for the user. I worked many years with Oracle Discoverer and it works this way. What's the point of offering a choice for which no data will be available? The user has to guess for which option will he get results?

Comment: You can always force the filters to check your fact tables, sure. As soon as you choose for example a product and then further restrict by an unrelated dimension like geography, then the restraint will go over the fact and only retrieve what really contains data.

Yes, Disco worked differently but OBI has analyses and prompts as absolutely independent and re-usable objects. Think LEGO for adults. Plug them together any way you want.

If you force your prompt to be tied to ONE specific analysis and hence set of data it becomes unusable for any other usage. That means more one-shot

Comment: one-use objects in the catalog that you need to manage and maintain. Now imagine a change happens in a source and you need to adapt all objects built on that. Change 5 objects re-usable objects? Or change 500 one-shot ones?

Comment: Offering choices for where there's no data....well...how would you know? You can only know if you restrict and cut down a data set to pretty much a static, unchanging thing.  What about tomorrow? What if there is a new product? What if you re-assign product to a different sales rep and they have personal data visibility applied? What if additional data gets added to the model?

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful comments. You are right, I suppose I need to become accustomed to a new way of thinking. However, I will try with a different example: imagine the column prompt does not contain Months (that actually only have 12 different values) but, for example, Service name or any other column with lots of different values. When the user needs to select a value from the choice list of the prompt, it will be a trial-and-error process until he picks up a service for which some data is displayed.

Comment: Ok let's use service name. In general: for analytics you pull your prompt data normally from dimensions. Dimensions contain all your services. The situation "no data" only comes when you the read from facts. And reading from facts can, again, always lead to the situation where nothing comes back. but take a step back: Should every user see very services? If no,then you can immediately put some filtering on the dimension to only show users what they should see (like being responsible for services). I definitely counsel you to think about what you want to do exactly since your question is just

Comment: quite weird conceptually. You CAN NOT know if anything in your prompts should pull data before you're done selecting. One dimension attribute on its own? Sure. But what when you start combining with date, geography, user, etc? What when you keep the prompt and change the data you're looking at? What if you don't want to see service name by country - where you get no data for whatever reason - but then you change to service name by product line or business unit. And then data comes back. The alternative is to force all prompts to magically check all possible combination possibilities of all

Comment: prompts which exist on the page against the fact data and only bring back values where the COMBINATION of prompted values retrieves data. With that you can kiss goodbye flexibility and performance. Because in the worst case you'd need to check many different fact tables, not just one.

Comment: Chris, I have to admit that your comments are making me think a lot :) But maybe you are complicating things too much. Our analysis, in general, are far much simpler. In your comments you say "Should every user see very services? If no,then you can immediately put some filtering on the dimension to only show users what they should see"... and that's exactly what I want to do!!

Comment: For that reason, I put a FILTER in my analysis to only take services of type BUSINESS, because the name of the Analysis is precisely "BUSINESS SERVICES". So, when a user run this analysis in a dashboard, obviously he does not expect to see in the service name prompt other services that are not BUSINESS services. But, as the prompt does not take into consideration the filter it is actually showing the full list of services.

Comment: "For that reason, I put a FILTER in my analysis" - In that case you don't. You filter the prompt and the prompt then hands that over to the analysis :) You can change the LSQL to include a WHERE clause. Or you can add business model filtering in the RPD based on user or application role. Then it will be applied systematically and for every usage of that attribute. No matter where.

Comment: Now we are getting to a solution! OK. I do not want to enter a filter at RPD level for this particular case, as it is not dependent neither on user nor role. I would rather try the first option you mention about filtering the prompt by changing the SQL to include a WHERE clause but I cannot see where can I do that. Thanks again!!

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks so much for your time and generosity!

Comment: No problem. Any time.